# Let fontspec handle bold font automatically

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I recently installed a commercial font called [Monospace 821](http://www.fonts.com/font/bitstream/monospace-821#product_top). The font came in ttf format and I installed it as usual in a Linux machine.

Problem is that when I use

```
\textbf{Bold}
```

the resulting text is not printed in bold. To get the bold I'm using the following workaround:

```
\newfontfamily\mybold{Monospace821BTBold}
\newcommand{\mytextbf}[1]{\mybold #1}
```

My question is: is this normal or is there a way to get the bold font automatically when using `\textbf{...}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\monobt{Monospace821BT}
\newfontfamily\mybold{Monospace821BTBold}
\newcommand{\mytextbf}[1]{\mybold #1}
\begin{document}

{\monobt \textbf{this is not bold}}

\mytextbf{this is bold}
\end{document}
```

The monospaced font is not used as `tt` font, I have another font set to `\setmonofont{...}` so I can't put Monospace 821 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `fontspec` is unable to find the bold font associated to a medium series font, uou can use the normal options also with `\newfontfamily`:

```
\newfontfamily{\monobt}{Monospace821BT}[
  BoldFont={Monospace821BTBold}
]
```

and then

```
{\monobt\textbf{This is bold}}
```

should work.

Notice that the options should go *before* the font name with older versions of `fontspec`.